# How to reuse hashing function of string class for custom class in unordered map?

Tags: c++, hash, tr1, unordered-map, hash-function

I'm defining an unordered_map in C++ like the following:

```
unordered_map<CustomClass, int, CustomClassHash, CustomClassEq> myMap;
```

Assume I have been able to successfully define CustomClassEq. I want the hash of CustomClass viz. CustomClassHash to delegate to the hash of a string attribute inside the class. Is there a way that I could reuse the hashing function of string class inside the definition of CustomClassHash?

This is what I want to do:

```
struct CustomClassHash {
    long operator()(const CustomClass &c) const {
        string s = c.getString();
        // TODO: return the hash of s
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use : 

`return hash<string>()(c.get_name());`

Check the second comment of the post

[object as a key of unordered map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685307/object-as-a-key-of-unordered-map)